# Automatically Pickup Active Directory Login Details

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, authentication, active-directory

I have the following in my web.config file.

```
<location path="login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

This means that upon going to the login page the user is prompted to enter there Active Directory login to access the page. Is there anyway to make IIS/ASP.net automatically pick up this information so I can use the following

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

On the login page to establish an automatic login.

If this string is not empty I will check it against a database table containing a list of permitted users that is managed by an external application (also manages permissions within the website)

The reason I would like to have this process automated is that if the user does not have there name entered into this database they should be presented with a normal login screen which has various override logins (forms authentication) naturally whilst this is not automated the end user would have to enter a login (which may be valid within the context of the active directory) but invalid as far as the web application is concerned.

I have found that removing the section

```
<deny users="?"/>
```

Does not prompt for an active directory login, but also the

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name = String.Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Windows Authentication set on and Anonymous Authentication set off on IIS

[image]

In case your Windows Server doesn't include a windows authentication scheme:

Open up Server Manager (one way to do this is by right clicking the computer node from within the start menu and choosing  Manage). Expend the Roles node. Right click the Web Server (IIS) and choose Add Role Services. You'll get the following wizard, just scroll down a bit and check Windows Authentication under the security node.

http://weblogs.asp.net/zroiy/archive/2008/08/17/missing-windows-authentication-provider-for-iis-7-on-windows-server-2008.aspx

Comment: For some reason I am not seeing these options...   https://www.dropbox.com/s/9voixa50t8xylsu/NoWindows.png

Comment: See updated answer. It seems you need to add a role service for windows authentication

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on this one. Currently don't have permission to do this.